# error ITMS-9000: Invalid Bundle. The bundle my_app.app does not support the minimum OS Version specified in the Info.plist

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I 've build an IOS app using phonegap builder. And whem I try to upload my app in App Store I get the following error.
error ITMS-9000: Invalid Bundle. The bundle my_app.app does not support the minimum OS Version specified in the Info.plist

Has anyone seen this before? Any suggestions??
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Faced with the same error with Flex build (AIR15 (tried release and beta) with Starling).

Answer (score 0):

Out of sudden, and without changing anything at all, today seems to work fine! 
Application Loader throws only a warning:

> WARNING ITMS-9000: "The executable 'Payload/myApp.app' is nor a
>   Position Independent Executable. Please ensure that your build
>   settings are configured to create PIE executables. For more
>   information refer to Technical Q&A QA1788 - Building a Position
>   Independent Executable in the IOS Developer Library"

but I ignored it and I managed to upload my app with the old .ipa file (without need of rebuilding it)